# How to display django model column values horizontally on django template

Tags: django, templates, model

my issue is displaying the model data on django template horizontally. I have a model named "Main" with 3 columns. When I display on the template it looks like this-

[image]

I want to filter it by category that will look like this-

```
Main.objects.filter(category='food')
```

[image]

My goal is to show the category name on the template with the price horizontally on the side with plus signs. It should look something like this-

```
food= 8+10+11
```

I tried for...in loop both on template and on views.py both failed. Tried something like this- print(f"{i.category}={i.price}+") with for loop. Didn't work.

output+=f'{i.price}+' with a for loop, holding it in a variable and display that variable on template. Different combinations of those, all failed.

Since += is mainly for integers, I tried with i.price without turning it into a string, failed.

Most answers I found here on "displaying model data horizontally on Django template" are about using css to display form elements side by side,which I know how to do and not exactly my problem.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Here is my models.py

```
class Main(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`views.py` -

```
def products(request):
    products = Main.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products}
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

and the HTML template -

```
<div class="card card-body">
   <table class="table">
      <tr>
         <th>Product</th>
         <th>Category</th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      {% for i in products %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{i.name}}</td>
         <td>{{i.category}}</td>
         <td>{{i.price}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </table>
</div>
```

Not the entire template but you get the idea. Very basic.

Comment: Could you mention how each of the things you've tried fail?

Comment: I keep adjusting the code to get the solution, so didn't keep them all. But can definitely try to recreate that. But I got an answer, possible solution. Will try that first and probably got back to it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**views.py:**

```
def products(request):
    foods = Main.objects.filter(category='food').values_lis('category', flat=True)
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'foods': foods})
```

**index.html:**

```
<div class="card card-body">
  <p> food:  
     <span> 
       {% for food in foods %}
         {{ food }} {% if not forloop.last %}+{% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
     </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would not be able to think it on my own. Thank you so much for the input. Will try it out tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your answer.